# How fix brew errors on 10.8

Tags: macos, homebrew

I have some troubles with brew doctor:

```
Error: /usr/local/Library/Formula/enchant.rb:44: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND
Please report this bug:
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:40:in `require'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:40:in `klass'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:90:in `get_formula'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:175:in `factory'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:432:in `factory'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:366:in `each'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:364:in `each'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb:818:in `check_for_linked_keg_only_brews'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb:1095:in `send'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb:1095:in `doctor'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb:1094:in `each'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb:1094:in `doctor'
/usr/local/Library/brew.rb:95:in `send'
/usr/local/Library/brew.rb:95
```

How can I fix these errors? Is it critical to fix them all or I may ignore some of them? Thank you.

Comment: off-topic. try http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: i tried. But i'm not shure to use chmod and chown on this folders and files. is it realy necessary? may be another ways? Or i can do it?

Comment: Yes, chown help's me. But i steel have error